# Pass Java object to Handlebars.js helper

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, templates, handlebars.js

I am wondering whether it is possible to pass a Java object created in a controller of a Spring MVC application, through Handlebars helper methods to the client side.

For example, if in the controller I create a map and pass it to my view:

```
    public ModelAndView myController(HttpServletRequest req) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/myview.jsp");

        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1L, "a");
        map.put(2L, "b");

        mav.addObject("MyMap", map);

        return mav;
    }
```

... and my view being something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- I want to pass my map to this helper function -->
        <div id="mymap">{{buildStringFromMap "MyMap"}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then have the actual Handlebars helper in Javascript that does something with that map, like this:

```
            Handlebars.registerHelper('buildStringFromMap', function (myMap) {
                var a = myMap[1L]; // a == "a" here
               // do whatever with the map
            });
```

Obviously this doesn't work because I didn't actually pass my Map object, but a String "MyMap". Is there a way to pass in the actual Map object?

Comment: Convert your map object to javascript map in view and then pass it to handlebar helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a whole Map into your HTML and then iterate and use your helper (aCustomHelper). The '@key' keyword refers to the key of the map and the 'this' keyword refers to the value of the map (example-map-object).

```
{{#each example-map-object}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{{this}}}</td>
        <td>{{{@key}}}</td>
        <td>{{{aCustomHelper @key this}}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

In the example below, you can see how you can access a Set object by key and value:

```
<select>
    {{#each example-set-object}}
          <option value="{{@value}}">{{@key}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

In the example below, you can see how you can access a Map by it's key values, which is very handy indeed:

```
{{#each example-map-object}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{{this.id}}}</td>
        <td>{{{this.customerName}}}</td>
        <td>{{{this.date}}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

So the answer to your question is that YES, you can most certainly do what you want and pass the whole map as a parameter to your helper method.

```
{{yourHelper example-map-object}}
```